# C++ dynamic_cast dowcast fails

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

While writing my first big project in C++, I encountered a problem which I wasn´t able to solve using google and documentation alone.

I cannot figure out, why this dynamic_cast fails, even though r is pointing to a MeshRenderer Object.

```
for (RenderEventConsumer* r : d->getConsumers())
{
    glUseProgram(mPickingShader->apiID);
    MeshRenderer* m = dynamic_cast<MeshRenderer*>(r); //returns nullptr
    if (m)
    {
        glUniform1ui(uPickingID, m->getOwner()->getID());
        m->getMesh()->getUtillityBuffer().draw();
    }
}
```

The class RenderEventConsumer has a virtual method and is a base of MeshRenderer.

```
class MeshRenderer : public Component {...}
class Component : public GameObject {...}
class GameObject : protected TickEventConsumer, protected RenderEventConsumer, protected PhysicsTickEventConsumer {...}
```

According to Visual Studio the vftable of r is correct.
[image]

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow, please let me know if I violated any guideline or am missing relevant information.

EDIT: Although I know the answer now, I reproduced the error with a standalone example for clarity:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class RenderEventConsumer
{
    virtual void onRender() {};
};

class RenderEventDispatcher
{
    std::vector<RenderEventConsumer*> mConsumers;
public:
    const std::vector<RenderEventConsumer*>& getConsumers()
    {
        return mConsumers;
    }
    void registerRenderEventConsumer(RenderEventConsumer* consumer)
    {
        mConsumers.push_back(consumer);
    }
};

class GameObject : protected RenderEventConsumer {}; //changing this to public fixes dynamic_cast
class Component : public GameObject {};
class MeshRenderer : public Component 
{
public:
    void setup(RenderEventDispatcher& d) 
    {
        d.registerRenderEventConsumer(this);
    }
    void onRender() override { }
};

int main()
{
    RenderEventDispatcher d;
    MeshRenderer* pt = new MeshRenderer();
    pt->setup(d);
    
    for (RenderEventConsumer* r : d.getConsumers())
    {
        MeshRenderer* m = dynamic_cast<MeshRenderer*>(r);
        if (m)
        {
            std::cout << "not nullptr\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "nullptr\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `d`? What does `d->getConsumers()` return? How do you add elements to whatever container you have? Could there be [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) along the way? Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: @AndyG RenderEventConsumer doesn´t derive from any classes.

Comment: Your title is misleading as well, as you don't do a "virtual_cast" but a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: It's probably because `GameObject` is using `protected` inheretance from `RenderEventConsumer`, I don't remember the rules in such scenario exactly, but I think if you were to use a `dynamic_cast` outside of `GameObject` or it's children method, it will fail, change it to `public` and see if it works.

Comment: I suspect you have a bug in the code you have not provided.  A [mcve] would help a lot, and pay particular attention the *minimal* part.  Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kaldrr.
The solution was to derive publicly from RenderEventConsumer.

```
class GameObject : public TickEventConsumer, public RenderEventConsumer, public PhysicsTickEventConsumer {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because `RenderEventConsumer` is a base `MeshRenderer`, that doesn't mean that all classes derived from `RenderEventConsumer` are also (derived from) `MeshRenderer`.

If `MeshRenderer` isn't (a base of) the dynamic type of the pointed object, then `dynamic_cast` will return null.

Here is an example of how that may happen:

```
struct another_derived : RenderEventConsumer {} instance;
RenderEventConsumer* r = &instance;

// null, even through r is RenderEventConsumer*
dynamic_cast<MeshRenderer*>(r);
```

---

If you find that you need to use `dynamic_cast`, that implies that the design is broken. Consider using for example the visitor pattern instead.

Comment: We have `MeshRenderer` -> `Component` -> `GameObject` -> (protected) `RenderEventConsumer`...

Comment: But partial definitions of its derived classes are (in wrong order from compilation point of view)...

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh yeah. The inverted order broke by brain.